# How to select several words, and remove all lines that contain those words?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF85D.png). I want to get rid of the clutter, and leave only things like ID, and TEXT, but remove the other things, such as type, date, date_unixtime, edited, from, etc.

I tried the following command, to try remove just all lines with just one word (I don't know how to combine the needed words in the command) but it produced a 0 byte file (see [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lONfL.png)). Note: it didn't throw any errors.

```
<1n6Envrionment.json awk '! "date_unixtime"' >1n6Envrionment2.json
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, add the text itself to the question. Then people who want to help have some sample input to work with.

Answer (score 3):

A better tool to manipulate json files is [jq](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/jq.1.html). jq understands json so it will ensure that its output is a valid json file.

You can install jq by running

```
sudo apt install -y jq
```

then

```
jq 'del(.date_unixtime)' 1n6Envrionment2.json
```

would delete the date_unixtime field for instance, similarly

```
jq 'del(.text_entities)' 1n6Envrionment2.json
```

would delete text_entities and all its children. jq has an [extensive matching capability](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) for its filters so you can either run it multiple times or, depending on exactly what you want to remove you might be able to construct a single filter that removes everything.

Answer (score 1):

Grep can do this. To exclude lines with the word `date`:

```
grep -v "date" 1n6Envrionment2.json
```

To exclude more words, separate with an escaped `|`, like this:

```
grep -v "date\|date_unixtime\|edited" 1n6Envrionment2.json
```

You can redirect back to the same file (`> 1n6Envrionment2.json`) if you want to write the changes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to @Artur Meinild's

**Example Task**

Remove all lines including `thisname` or `othername`

**Example File filename**

```
There is one line
then another
but then there is thisname
and then there is not
then othername
then both thisname and othername
```

**Example Code**

```
grep -vE "thisname|othername" filename
```

This uses regular expressions and is therefore more powerful as far as I know than the solution given by Meinild.

If you only want to match complete words, use:

```
grep -vE "[ ]{0,1}thisname[ ]{0,1}|[ ]{0,1}othername[ ]{0,1}" filename
```

which means that a word is only allowed to be surrounded by nothing or a space.

**Example Output**

```
There is one line
then another
and then there is not
```